# Nothing appears while using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I have a problem with react Router.

So i am building the nav of an website and when i'm doing the routes, nothing appears.

Would you help me please to see what i'm doing wrong?

The page stays white. Nothing appears, even the root doesnt see the homepage.
........................................................................................
Homepage:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from '../allpages/navbar/Navbar';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import Contact from "../contact/Contact";
import About from "../about/About";
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <Navbar />
                <Routes>
                    <Route  path="/about" element={About} />
                    <Route  path="/contact" element={Contact} />
                    <Route exact path="/" element={Home} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>

            <h3>Home</h3>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Navbar:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    BrowserRouter as  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
   
            <div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        
        
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

main app:

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/home/Home'
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Home />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

contact:

```
import React from 'react';

const Contact = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Contact</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Contact
```

About:

```
import React from 'react';
const About = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>About</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default About
```

Comment: change this line `<Route exact path="/" element={Home} />` to `<Route exact path="/" element=<div>test</div> />` as `Home` cant call itself again and render again when its already rendered

Comment: Still nothing  appears

Comment: reorder the routes, put home root `/` route on top of everything, `<Route exact path="/" element={Home} /><Route  path="/about" element={About} /><Route  path="/contact" element={Contact} / ` replace `BrowserRouter as  Link` with `Link` only

Comment: i am getting this error : "```Uncaught Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.``

Comment: import {
    BrowserRouter as  Link
} from "react-router-dom"; // inside Navbar
 - here's your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

So besides this typo:

```
 { BrowserRouter as Link } // use just Link
```

which is inside Navbar.js

I would also use recommended approach by React-Router team. Which uses `<Switch>` component to wrap pages. You are using `Routes` instead, idk if this is even valid.
You can check this example: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/basic
which is really similar to your code.

Comment: That is because starting from react-router-dom v6, <Switch /> has been replaced by <Routes />. The problem was indeed the "BrowserRouter"  thx!

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know that. Tnx! :)

Answer (score 0):

What versión is you using? You might be out of dated

````
<React.Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/*" element={<Outlet />}>
                  
                    <Route path="informacion-financiera" element={<Financiera />} />
                    <Route path="derechos-de-autor" element={<Author />} />
                    <Route 
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </React.Suspense>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

What versión is you using? You might be out of dated

````
<React.Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/*" element={<Outlet />}>
                  
                    <Route path="informacion-financiera" element={<Financiera />} />
                    <Route path="derechos-de-autor" element={<Author />} />
                    <Route 
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </React.Suspense>
    ```


You have browserRouter as Link so yow links are not links
````